# How to get single item in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a database with cars, and each car has an id. To get all cars I would go at this route `api/cars/`, now I am trying to implement getting a single car which has id 1 and this is my urls:

```py
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('api/cars/', CarsAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/cars/:id/', CarAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/tours/ongoing/', CarListOngoingAPI.as_view())
]
```

And this is my views for first path and second,

```py
class CarsAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarsSerializer

# GET single car with id
class CarAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarsSerializer

class CarListOngoingAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarsSerializer
```

And here is my Car model:

```py
class Car(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    ongoing = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

First class returs a list of all car models. Now I need to find a way to implement two other types, one where an argument is passed in, in my case id `api/cars/:id/` and the second `api/cars/ongoing/`, I should say that these are just hypothethetical cases, just for learning purposes and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.path).

Comment: @Melvyn I have read the docs, but I just could not implmenent it. Could you help??

Comment: Then why is there `:id` instead of `<type:name>`, such as `<int:pk>`? That really is all that needs fixing for Retrieve. For ongoing, I guess your goal is to display only cars with ongoing=True? [See here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) for `get_queryset()`.

Comment: @Melvyn how can I filter on that parameter ongoing=True with the get_queryset() method?

Comment: @Melvyn nvm, but thanks for the help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite bad at Django myself, from what what I've gathered you can simple do something like so:

```py
def car_id(request, pk):
    """url: api/car/pk"""
    try:
        car = models.Car.objects.get(id=pk)
    except models.Car.DoesNotExist:
        # Whoopsie
        return HttpResponseNotFound(
            json.dumps({"ERR": f"car  with id {id} not found"}),
            content_type="application/json",
        )

    # Serialise your car or do something with it
    return JsonResponse(CarSerializer(car).data)
```

(Assuming you have your api's `urlpatterns` defined like so)

```py
urlpatterns = [
...
    r"api/car/(?P<id>\d+)/", views.car_id
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of my problem, I just had to fix the urls to:

```py
urlpatterns = [ 
    path('api/cars/', CarsAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/cars/<int:pk>/', CarAPI.as_view()),
    path('api/tours/ongoing/', CarListOngoingAPI.as_view())
]
```

And for the second, I learned how to filter a query set by overriding `get_queryset()`

```py
class CarListOngoingAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
    # queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Car.objects.filter(ongoing=True)
```